# How to edit or append audio recording?

Tags: android, audio, append, edit, recording

I am creating one application in Android. My application record audio and store it on SD card
and show in list format. I do this all but i need to edit this audio like suppose i open recording
then i need to start this recording again from ending and able to append audio in that recording.

Like: Suppose my recoding "MyRecord01" time is 04.06 sec and i want to add more audio in the recording
then it must start from 04.07 and add some audio.

I search lot of but didn't find anything relative. Please direct me to any link or any reference.
Or give me any hint.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.pastie.org/2165869) is the code you need. Hope it works for you.

If I identified your problem wrong, feel free to comment and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not too difficult. The key is to understand how the audio you've recorded is formatted. It's easiest if you use an uncompressed format, like WAV or AIFF. Here is one (of many) explanations of the WAV file formats: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Most WAV files can be easily appended to if the data chunk is last (this may be a requirement of the format, I can't recall for sure). If it is not last, you'll first have to copy the file and modify it such that the data chunk is last. This can be a time-consuming step if the file is large.

Once that's done, you simply append new audio data to the data chunk and update a few pieces of data elsewhere in the file, such as the data chunk size (in the the data chunk), the chunk size (in the RIFF descriptor) and the Subchunk1 size (in the fmt chunk). (That will all make more sense to you once you read the explanation.) You may want to do something with those data while you are appending so that it is easy to fix in case your app crashes durring the append -- you don't want to corrupt the user's data.

The process is similar for AIFFs, but there are differences in the details.

For MP3s, I am not 100% sure off the top of my head how this would work. If memory serves the process is conceptually easier because MP3 files are structured as a series of independent chunks, and each chunk has its own mini header. Theoretically, you can just append more chunks. In practice it is going to be more complex, though, because of the compression and things like ID3 tags.

Comment: how to implement in Android? Any relative article?

Comment: I'm not aware of a relavant article that specifically covers appending to WAV/AIFFs, but I've just given you all the tools you need. You are going to have to digest them and come up with your own solution.